# Error: While running abbreviation_column_method. Failed with exception: Column is not iterable

Tags: python, pyspark, etl

```py
abbreviation_mapping = {
        "E": "Europe",
        "A": "US/Canada",
        "S": "South America",
        "O": "Australia",
        "Z": "New Zealand",
        "N": "New Delhi/Kolkata",
        "U": "New Delhi/Kolkata",
        "": "New Delhi/Kolkata"
        # Add more mappings as needed
    }
def abbreviation_column(self,df,abbreviation_mapping,col_name):
        """
        This function will replace abbreviation with long form
        :param df: input dataframe
        :param abbreviation_mapping: Give abbreviation in the form of dictionary
        :param col_name: column name on which abbreviation_column need to apply
        :return: df
        """
        try:
            df = df.withColumn(
                col_name,
                when(cast(col(col_name).isin(abbreviation_mapping.keys()),int)| (col(col_name) == ""),
                     col(col_name).replace("", "New Delhi/Kolkata").replace(*abbreviation_mapping.items()))
                .otherwise(col(col_name))
            )
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"Error: While running abbreviation_column_method. Failed with exception: {e}")
        return df
```

## I am expecting all abbreviation in the column 'dst' should be replaced with their long # form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a udf for this, refer to the below code

```html
abbreviation_mapping = {
        "E": "Europe",
        "A": "US/Canada",
        "S": "South America",
        "O": "Australia",
        "Z": "New Zealand",
        "N": "New Delhi/Kolkata",
        "U": "New Delhi/Kolkata",
        "": "New Delhi/Kolkata"
        # Add more mappings as needed
    }

abbreviationUDF = udf(lambda z: abbreviation_mapping[z]) 

def abbreviation_column(df,abbreviation_mapping,col_name):
        """
        This function will replace abbreviation with long form
        :param df: input dataframe
        :param abbreviation_mapping: Give abbreviation in the form of dictionary
        :param col_name: column name on which abbreviation_column need to apply
        :return: df
        """
        try:
            df = df.withColumn(col_name, abbreviationUDF(col(col_name)))
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"Error: While running abbreviation_column_method. Failed with exception: {e}")
        return df
```

Answer (score 0):

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from itertools import chain

## User-specified abbreviations and their corresponding long forms

```
abbreviation_mapping = {
    "E": "Europe",
    "A": "US/Canada",
    "S": "South America",
    "O": "Australia",
    "Z": "New Zealand",
    "N": "New Delhi/Kolkata",
    "U": "New Delhi/Kolkata",
    "": "New Delhi/Kolkata"
    # Add more mappings as needed
}

mapping_expr = create_map([lit(x) for x in chain(*abbreviation_mapping.items())])

df = df.withColumn("dst",mapping_expr[df["dst"]])

df.show()
```